# How Do i check permission of a folder to a user in Google Drive SDK?

Tags: java, jquery, google-drive-api

I have Google-Drive integrated into my website. I am using Google Drive Java API v2. I have a situation when a user logs in to my website i need to check his permissions for the Google Drive Folder(say Folder1) that is associated with the site and based on the permisson i need to show him the content. All the info i have with respect to this user is `Google Drive FolderID, EmailAddress and access token`. How do i check the users permissions to the give folder or not? Here is my code.

I am trying to show the Google folders in my site by making a ajax call to Google giving then access token/FileID. IF the user don't have permissions then it is sending the 404 error saying File not Found show as below. But it should show me a "permission error". The File do Exist.

```
function showLinkedGoogleFolder(fileId) {
    $.ajax({
            timeout: 10000, // Timeout (in ms) = 10sec
            url: _getGoogleDriveUrl(fileId),
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                    callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
                }
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (typeof(errorCallback) === 'function') {
                    errorCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
                }
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                if (typeof(completeCallback) === 'function') {
                    completeCallback(jqXHR, textStatus);
                }
            }
        });
}

    function _getGoogleDriveUrl(fileId) {
        var host = "../"; // relative path to proxy
        var proxyName = "proxy/google-drive-lti";
        var result = host+proxyName+'/drive/v2/files/';
        if ($.trim(fileId) !== '') {
            result = result + fileId;
        }
        return result;
    }
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "File not found: 0BwwFUSF0YgJgUHo2Y0pBOW5lNmc"
       }
      ],
      "code": 404,
      "message": "File not found: 0BwwFUSF0YgJgUHo2Y0pBOW5lNmc"
     }
    }
```

Comment: 404 is correct. If the user has no permission to a file, then Google will not even leak the fact that the file does or does not exist. This is a standard security process. It's a bit like logging on to a website using a username and password. Sites don't say 'the username is correct but the password is wrong'. They simply say 'no match for the given username and password'.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have his access/refresh token: Unless you gave the permission yourself and remembered the permissionId, you can't.
If you do have his token: then use the access token to attempt to list the folder contents. See if it fails with "no permission".

Comment: IS their a way we can check this in javaAPis. can you refer me some link how this id done?

Comment: Right now i see that google is sending that a 404 error message saying that "File not Found:OBEWDSFSFSFSF" instead of No permission error

Comment: Its all in the documentation. Look it up and post the code you tried it.

Comment: Will be posting shortly.

Comment: where is the documentation i can check for the permission of the users based on ACCESS TOKEN and FILEID

Comment: just make the list call. see what error it shows. might be "not found" instead of "permission error"

Comment: drive.permissions().list(fileId).execute(); I have used this Java API call and it returned what i wanted. Thanks